# java6 HttpsUrlConnection error:javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake

Tags: ssl, https, java-6, httpsurlconnection

I write a demo to access a server with java HttpsUrlConnection.
I implement the X509TrustManager interface with MyX509TrustManager to trust all certificates.

It works fine with JDK7 and JDK8, but when use JDK6 and JDK5, error happens:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:882)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1188)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1215)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1199)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:434)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:166)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1014)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:230)
```

For server side, running on Tomcat 8 and JDK8.

**EDIT** I add -Djavax.net.debug=ssl,handshake and find following:

```
*** main, WRITE: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 177 main, WRITE: SSLv2 client hello message, length = 173
main, received EOFException: error main, handling exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake
main, SEND TLSv1 ALERT: fatal, description = handshake_failure
main, WRITE: TLSv1 Alert, length = 2 main, called closeSocket()
main, called close() main, called closeInternal(true)
```

Comment: You probably need to disable SSLv3, but you would need to post the output of `-Djavax.net.debug=ssl,handshake` for us to be sure. Could also be a client certificate issue.

Comment: I add -Djavax.net.debug=ssl,handshake and find following:***
main, WRITE: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 177
main, WRITE: SSLv2 client hello message, length = 173
main, received EOFException: error
main, handling exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake
main, SEND TLSv1 ALERT:  fatal, description = handshake_failure
main, WRITE: TLSv1 Alert, length = 2
main, called closeSocket()
main, called close()
main, called closeInternal(true)

Comment: @EJB thanks very much. I try this code:System.setProperty("https.protocols","TLSv1"); and it works fine in JDK5, JDK6, JDK7, JDK8.

Comment: have you try ssllabs.com to check if the sever is compatible with java 6 / 7 ?

Comment: I test on my local with different java versions.